# Windows CE - SetPowerRequirement() - CPU name?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-ce, cpu

I'm trying to keep the CPU at full power to avoid the crash of a program on sleep button press. SetPowerRequirement() expects the name of the device as a first parameter. Where can i find the name of the CPU ? And what "name" is it exactly ?

Thank you :)

Comment: You'll probably need to iterate through the list of devices to find what you're looking for. Perhaps staring with [PlatformDeviceListInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919405.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found a way to disable the button through the power settings from control panel.

Answer (score 1):

SetPowerRequirement works on drivers that support power management. Unless there is a driver that exposes this feature for the CPU you can't force it to stay powered and even in that case you can't prevent the system from going into suspend state when the sleep button is pressed. 
If you have access to the BSP you may implement a way to configure the system to ignore the sleep button, this may be done using a KernelIoControl.